# Jetty not starting in installing ckan from package ubuntu 14.04

Tags: solr, jetty, ubuntu-14.04, ckan

I am trying to install CKAN from package on ubuntu 14.04 using [the latest docs](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/installing/install-from-package.html).
So while setting up solr when I execute the command:

```
sudo service jetty restart
```

I get this on my terminal:

```
* Starting Jetty servlet engine. jetty
* /var/run/jetty.pid exists, but jetty was not running. Ignoring /var/run/jetty.pid
/etc/init.d/jetty: 274: /etc/init.d/jetty: /usr/sbin/rotatelogs: not found
* Jetty servlet engine started, reachable on http://ammar-HP-ProBook-450-G4:8983/. jetty                                                [fail]
```

Hence I cannot see a solr welcome page on `localhost:8983/solr/`

Help Please...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why its used a different hostname to localhost, but it sounds it is running on this slightly different address and you can simply configure CKAN to use it:

```
solr_url=http://ammar-HP-ProBook-450-G4:8983/solr
```

Comment: @Ammar were you able to solve this issue?
i am facing same issue